# Get DataContext from TextBlock MouseDown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, mouseevent

Bound column in a ListView GridView

How to get the DataSource in a MouseDown event

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>  
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    MouseDown="NameCol_mousedown"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

This works in another project with a button in a ListView.

This is what it tried ...

Error Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'ListViewDragDrop.DocProp'.

The DataSource is DocProp.

```
private void NameCol_mousedown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;
    object data = tb.DataContext;
    dataSource = (DocProp)tb.DataContext;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this...

```
private void NameCol_mousedown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBlock)e.OriginalSource;
    var dataCxtx = tb.DataContext;
    var dataSource = (DocProp)dataCxtx;
}
```

Comment: That worked.  Please tell my why OriginalSource is required on TextBlock but not Button?

Comment: I can explain but MSDN explians it better... see their help on routed event args.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still having problems, this works fine as well.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var baseobj = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var myObject = baseobj.DataContext as (Object you expect);

    // Example: var myObject = baseobj.DataContext as Dog;
    // myObject.Bark();
}
```